# How to create this Neural Network in jupyter notebook and fix the error

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Getting The Data:

Read all the data in from the candyBar.txt that is included in your download. Store your data in regular python lists named:

```
x1 which represents if the candy was fruity flavored (1st column), 1 = fruity, 0 = not fruity
x2 which represents if the candy had caramel in it (2nd column) 1 = carmel, 0 = no caramel
x3 which represents if the candy had peanuts/almonds in it (3rd column) 1 = peanuts, 0 = no peanuts
x4 which represents if the candy was in the shape of a bar (4th column) 1 = bar, 0 = no bar
y which respresents if the candy was chocolate or not. 1 = had chocolate, 0 = did not have chocolate (5th Column)


#Get the Training Data from a file
import os
path = os.getcwd() + '\candyBar.txt'

x1=[]
x2=[]
x3=[]
x4=[]
y=[]
file = open(path,"r")
while True:
line = file.readline()
if not line:
    break
else:
    values = line.split(",")
    x1.append(float(values[0]))
    x2.append(float(values[1]))
    x3.append(float(values[2]))
    x4.append(float(values[3]))
    y.append(float(values[4].rstrip("\n")))
    file.close()
```

Get the size of the data set using the len(listName) function

```
  m = len(x1)
```

Convert the x1, x2, x3, x4 data to a np array using np.array(listName)

```
 #---------------FILL IN THE MISSING CODE----------------------
 x1 =  np.array(x1)
 x2 =  np.array(x2)
 x3 =  np.array(x3)
 x4 =  np.array(x4)
```

Combine them together using np.column_stack((col1Name, col2Name, col3Name, col4Name)). The ones are first, then x1, then x2, then x3, then x4

```
   #---------------FILL IN THE MISSING CODE----------------------
   x = np.column_stack((x1,x2,x3,x4))
   print(x)
```

Convert the y data to the transpose of a np array (Needed for the matrix multiplication that the functions do)

Use np.array([listName]).T

```
#---------------FILL IN THE MISSING CODE----------------------

y = np.array([y]).T
print(y)
```

Split the data set into a training data set and a test data set.

Use the first 60 values (0->60) from the data set to train, and the remainder to test on (60 ->m)
Use listName[startValue:EndValue]

```
#---------------FILL IN THE MISSING CODE----------------------

xTrain = x[0:60]
yTrain = y[0:60]
xTest =  x[60:m]
yTest =  y[60:m]
```

Set the parameters of the neural network

We need to specify how many input nodes, output nodes exist and how many nodes we wish to use in the hidden layer.

In the data set there are 4 inputs
In the data set there is 1 output
Let's use 3 nodes in hidden layer (You can pick anything, but beware of over and underfitting)

```
#---------------FILL IN THE MISSING CODE----------------------
inputNeurons = model.add(Dense(4,input_dim=3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
hiddenNeurons = model.add(Dense(3,init='uniform', activation='relu'))
outputNeurons = model.add(Dense(1,init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1712/1009970142.py in 
1 #---------------FILL IN THE MISSING CODE----------------------
----> 2 inputNeurons = model.add(Dense(4,input_dim=3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
3 hiddenNeurons = model.add(Dense(3,init='uniform', activation='relu'))
4 outputNeurons = model.add(Dense(1,init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where have you defined ```model```?

Comment: No, but how to add the neurons without that command or downloading packages(Tensorflow,Keras,etc)